# could not get json data in jquery in mvc

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I am developing application in asp.net MVC
My Script is :

```
 $(document).ready
     (
       function() {

        var officerid = document.getElementById('officerid').value;
        url = "/TasksToOfficer/Calender/" + officerid;

     var data=   function() 
                {
               $.ajax(
               {
                         type: 'GET',
                         url: url ,
                         dataType: 'json',
                         data: {'start' : start,'end' : end}
                }); 
                }; 


});
```

I am unable to get data from my controller action :

```
    [HttpGet]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]

 public JsonResult Calender(Guid id)
        { 
        List<TasksToOfficer> officersTasks = null;
        IList<CalendarDTO> tasksList = new List<CalendarDTO>();
        List<TasksToOfficer> officersTasksRecived = null;
            if (String.Compare(Convert.ToString(Session["Role"]), RolesEnum.Admin.ToString())!=0)
            {
                officersTasksRecived = tasks_to_officer_management.GetTasksToOfficers(id);
                foreach (TasksToOfficer tt in officersTasksRecived)
                {
                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(tt.Date);
                    tasksList.Add(new CalendarDTO
                    {
                    id=tt.Id,
                    title =tt.Description,
                    start = ToUnixTimespan(dt),
                    end = ToUnixTimespan(dt),
                    url =""}
                    );
                }
            }
          else
                if (String.Compare(Convert.ToString(Session["Role"]), RolesEnum.Officer.ToString()) != 0)
                {
                    officersTasksRecived = tasks_to_officer_management.GetTasksToOfficers(id);
                    foreach (TasksToOfficer tt in officersTasksRecived)
                    {
                        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(tt.Date);
                        tasksList.Add(new CalendarDTO
                        {
                            id = tt.Id,
                            title = tt.Description,
                            start = ToUnixTimespan(dt),
                            end = ToUnixTimespan(dt),
                            url = ""
                        }
                        );
                    }
                }
            JsonResult resultToView = Json(tasksList);
            return Json(resultToView,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

What should be the error ? In fact I am trying to attache the events on full calender control. I am picking up the records and building the JSon data in my action. but unable to show it on my calender. what I have to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess here, but I think the problem is that you're JSON serializing the JsonResult instead of `IList<CalendarDTO>`.  Instead of doing this:

```
  JsonResult resultToView = Json(tasksList);
  return Json(resultToView,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Why don't you try this?

```
  return Json(tasksList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getJson:

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 

    var officerid = document.getElementById('officerid').value;
    $.getJSON("/TasksToOfficer/Calender/" + officerid, function (data) {

        // do something with 'data'


        });

    });
```

You can point your browser to the action like this: http://yourdomain.com/TasksToOfficer/Calender/someID and see if you will get some data. Just replace 'someID' with some ID that exists.